# how to make exact match string url rewrite condition in htacces in php

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-rewriting

I want to make URL based on job id from website .

Below is the URL links of my filename:

http://www.example.com/jobseekers/apply-job.php?job_id=SRPL-255054

to:

http://www.example.com/jobseekers/apply-job/SRPL-255054

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^jobseekers/apply-job/(.*) jobseekers/apply-job.php?job_id=$1 [L]
```

Why is this tagged with php and mysql?

Comment: working fine when i type url  (jobseekers/apply-job/job_id) . But, automatically not redirecting to this url when i click on jobs  You can check this with url(http://srpl.in/jobseekers/apply-job.php?job_id=SRPL-255054) and http://srpl.in/jobseekers/who-is-hiring-new.php

Comment: If I understand, you mean your existing links are not overwritten? I don't know how to do this, my approach is writing them in the human-readable way, and then depend on the .htaccess.